# How to disable the Submit Button for a given duration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am building a login form. If the user attempts to login with invalid username/password for 3 attempts then the submit button must be disabled for a given duration.

How can I do that?

Here is my existing code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    string username = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
    string password = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
    String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Login", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    read.Read();

    if (read.HasRows)
    {
        Session["LoggedIn"] = "correct";
        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx", false);
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Wrong user/password";
        conn.Close();
    }

    if (System.Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Tries"]) == 2)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Exceeded 3 times Attempts.Please Login after some time";
        TextBox1.Enabled = false;
        TextBox2.Enabled = false;
        Button1.Enabled = false; // Button1 is the submit button
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, increment number of tries.
        ViewState["Tries"] = System.Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Tries"]) + 1;
        if (System.Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Tries"]) == 2)
            Label1.Text = "Exceeded 3 times Attempts.Please Login after some time";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can create a table in your code or in database something like

```
LockingTime

Userid   LockTime  LockedDateTime
1          30       01/03/2012 12:30
```

As per th table

```
UserId = id of the user locked
LockTime - amount of time user Get locked
LockDateTime - DateTime when user account locked
```

1. When user login fails three time you enter data in table as explained...
2. Now when user tries to login to system you should check

   `select * from table name userid=@userid and GetDate() > 
                     DATEADD (mi, LockTime, LockDateTime)`

**Note :** query is just a suggession this not actual query as i m not added lockdate + locktime which is depends on the database and function avilable

Comment: Thanks,Is it possible to do without database interaction

Comment: @Gopesh - as i writeen you can create datatable in you code and store it in catch or in application.itmes will do there is not stictly means to use database

Comment: ok,i will try..I am thinking abouta logic.get the current time and add some seconds or minutes to it.when that new time reached the button must be enabled.